# why two $scopes updates at the same time, duplicate data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, javascript-objects

I have this piece of code

```
  $scope.addToOrder = function(index) {
        var tempItem = $scope.item;

        if (tempItem[index].validate == true){
            if (_.isEmpty($scope.item2) == true) {
                $scope.item2.push(tempItem[index]);
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.item2.length; i++) {
                    if ($scope.item2[i] == tempItem[index]) {
                        break;
                    }

                    if (i == $scope.item2.length - 1) {
                        $scope.item2.push(tempItem[index]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to push data from one object to other (item to item2), it works well, but when i change data from item also item2 updates i dont want this.

What i missing?

Comment: btw, `if (tempItem[index].validate == true)` has the same meaning as `if (tempItem[index].validate)`. If you want to compare strict equal to boolean true, you should use `if (tempItem[index].validate === true)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is, you are using an object reference. Then if modify one, the othes one is modified too.

You could use [`angular.copy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

```
$scope.addToOrder = function(index) {
    var tempItem = $scope.item;

    var itemCopy = angular.copy(tempItem[index]);

    if (tempItem[index].validate == true){
        if (_.isEmpty($scope.item2) == true) {
            $scope.item2.push(itemCopy);
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.item2.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.item2[i] == tempItem[index]) {
                    break;
                }

                if (i == $scope.item2.length - 1) {
                    $scope.item2.push(itemCopy);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) to cope by value

```
 angular.copy($scope.item1, $scope.item2);
```

or

```
 $scope.item1 = angular.copy($scope.item2);
```